# Is there a Webservices API for the Stack Overflow Jobs CV Profile?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, api

Does Stack Overflow jobs have a webservices API?

I'd like to use it to keep my resume synced up with the one over at [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) which does have a webservices API for their CVs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API support. (Here's [the cross site duplicate on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/7815/can-we-source-job-postings-from-stackoverflow-com-jobs).)

But [the RSS feed](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?), as [mentioned on MetaSE,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81529/is-there-any-public-api-that-allow-me-to-get-a-list-of-jobs-from-careers-2-0) still works.